# python pyomo: declaration of discrete variable

Tags: python, pyomo

I am using pyomo for optimization modeling, including multiple continuous and discrete variables, but I am not clear how to define a discrete variable.The value of discrete variable is either 0 or 100.
my question is : how to define a discrete variable which value is either 0 or 100

thans all!

Comment: `myvar = 0` or `myvar = 100`

Comment: this question is based on pyomo, how to define a discrete variable which only have 2 possible values?

Comment: which means that the decision variable must be chosen in 0 and 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to declare a binary variable, e.g. `y`, in addition to your discrete variable, e.g. `myvar`.

Then, you need a constraint that says: `myvar = 100 * y`

If `y=0`, then `myvar` will necessarily be 0 too. If `y=1`, then `myvar` will be equal to 100.

I assume you would be able to express these in Pyomo syntax.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer perfectly solved my problem.Furthermore, if i want to declare a discrete variable which has more enumeration value, what should i do? i doubt if pyomo can solve this problem .

Comment: @zzzt233 You can make a set of the values of the enumeration values and a binary variable that is indexed by that set.  Post a second question if that is confusing and comment me.